# I deployed with an infinite durability supressor that I didn't research. Why?

Tags: xbox-one, metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

MGS 5: TPP On Xbox One

My normal loadout consists of a Renkov Tranq Conversion sniper rifle.
I got the legendary gunsmith, and customised this to add a grade 1 suppressor rather than researching the suppressor for this rifle (also a neat paintjob).

It works great - however something really unexpected happened the last time I deployed. My suppressor on this rifle had infinite durability, marked by a small infinity sign next to the suppressor bar on the weapon when equipped. After using several magazines of tranq rounds, the durability didn't go down.

I was about to start story mission 19, and was just running around stealing resource containers and capturing guard posts in Africa. I started at the oil well base, and moved south - east from there, capturing everything in my path, all the way to the mine, picking up everything I could - I wonder if this was an item I picked up and didn't notice.

I called in a supply drop multiple times and kept my infinite suppressor, but mistakenly called in a loadout (containing the same weapon) and lost it when I jumped in the box.

**TL;DR**

Where did my infinite suppressor come from - any chance I picked it up as an item while running through the various checkpoints and bases I was raiding? Is it a bug, exploit, or is there a random chance I will get one?

Comment: The infinity sign would lead me to believe it is not a glitch and was intentionally put there. Although I cannot speak to this.

Comment: @DangerZone That's not necessarily true. There could be an issue with the code on a level higher than that; in other words, something caused the game to think that giving him an "Infinite Suppressor" is appropriate, not just give him a glitched suppressor.

Comment: @LucasLeblanc, good point, but I was speaking more of that fact that an infinite suppressor in the game might not be a glitch. Of course him having one when he should not definitely could be. I should have been more clear.

Comment: Are you on PC? I've heard there's a glitch that allows you to put attachments on guns that you shouldn't normally be able to. Maybe you did that by mistake?

Comment: no, this is on xbone (I'll add to question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been playing the game since release and I have yet to see a situation, story mission or otherwise, where you get an infinite suppressor for mission-based reasons. Even training missions, like the shooting gallery missions on Mother Base -- they still wear off even though you get infinite ammo.

However, there IS a gun in the game that can get an unlimited durability suppressor: the Wu tranquilizer pistol at max upgrade level. My guess is that something in the game's code made it think that it should give you that suppressor instead of your normal one. I would definitely assume that it is a bug. If you can reproduce it, it would be worth documenting somewhere (and might shed more light on whether it is a bug or some weird hidden mechanic).

Comment: thanks for the answer. This tallies with my experience so far - I will try to reproduce but I'm not hopeful, this has only happened once and could be down to something really specific. I don't even have the infinite supressor for the wu pistol, so it definitely seems like a bug. I'll update my question if I manage to reproduce.

Comment: I have heard that the Burkov pistol also gets an infinite suppressor at max upgrade level, but I don't know for sure (and probably won't, because I don't want to use that weapon). That might also have something to do with it.